# Stripe payment method React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, stripe-payments

I am making a small ecommerce and I am using Stripe as a payment method. I got stuck on the request as I get this error:

"You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at [https://support.stripe.com/."](https://support.stripe.com/.%22)

My code:

back:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);

router.post("/payment", (req, res) => {
  stripe.charges.create(
    {
      source: req.body.tokenId,
      amount: req.body.amount,
      currency: "usd",
    },
    (stripeErr, stripeRes) => {
      if (stripeErr) {
        res.status(500).json(stripeErr);
      } else {
        res.status(200).json(stripeRes);
      }
    }
  );
});

module.exports = router;
```

Front:

```
 const publicToken = "pk_test..."
  const secretKey = "sk_test_..."
  const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart)
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [stripeToken, setStripeToken] = useState(null)
  const onToken = (token) => {
    setStripeToken(token)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const makeRequest = async () => {
      try{
        const res = await userRequest.post("/checkout/payment",{
          tokenId: stripeToken.id,
          amount: 500,
        }, {headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + publicToken }})
        navigate("/success", {data:res.data})
      } catch{}
    }
    stripeToken && makeRequest();
  }, [stripeToken, cart.total, navigate])
```

I tried to pass the authorization in a thousand ways and I keep getting the same error.

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `await userRequest.post("/checkout/payment"` - that is a request to your own site, is it not? Then trying to set an `Authorization` header for that one makes no sense to begin with. This is about wherever your code is actually communicating with the Stripe API.

Comment: This is likely about this part, `stripe.charges.create(...)`. And likely not something you have to manually add directly in there, but more likely related to configuration/setup. Have you verified that `const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);` correctly gets the value from the enviroment variables here in the first place?

Comment: I agree with what @CBroe said. It's most likely that the STRIPE_KEY is empty or wrong. One thing to add here is that you should never expose your `secretKey` in your frontend code.

Comment: I really love you! thanks! yes, "const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);" was not taking my secret key, I put it in manually and it works!

I'll fix it later, the important thing is that it was that and it works!

Yes, I also know that secret keys should not be revealed, it was just to show you the example.

I'm still learning and things like this are still overlooked.

thank you very much :)